# How do I notify TFS of build stats?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, build-automation

I am told TFS can accept data on build/test metrics from 3rd party continuous integration tools. Does anyone know how this works or have any good links for me? My google-fu seems weak today and I cannot find any info on this. We would like to have a short powershell script or app run at the end of the build and send all known metrics up to TFS so it could show up in certain reports. I actually would like things that (I think) should already have space for in the data warehouse for TFS BUild Server, but I will be using CC.NET. I am thinking build name, result (Pass/Fail), Number of Warnings, Number of Errors, Time, UnitTests Run, UnitTests Passed, Code Coverage, FxCop resultsThanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that there is not a ready made integration that does this yet.  The plug-in that links [CC.NET to TFS](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSCCNetPlugin) is available over at [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSCCNetPlugin) but this just lets CC.NET use TFS for version control and doesn't allow the results of the builds to be published back into TFS.

To get the data into TFS from CruiseControl.NET you have a couple of options.  You could write your own [custom TFS Data Warehouse Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130342.aspx) which is complex but ultimately flexible or you could use a combination of the [Team Build API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339575.aspx) and a little bit of vodoo to push data in to the TFS Build store that would also get pushed into the TFS Data warehouse.  However, this would be limited in TFS2008 as you would only be able to push data about the build and the unit tests but not things like Code Coverage.

That said, pushing data from CC.NET to TFS is something that I originally wanted to do. However in TFS2008 the built in build system was so good that I switched from using CC.NET to trigger the builds to using TFS to trigger and manage the build.  This had the advantage that all the stats stuff was taken care of automatically (and the built in UI in Visual Studio).  Because I moved to TFS2008 I then lost the motivation to get the CC.NET stuff built.

If anyone wanted to contribute a TFS build result publishing feature to the CC.NET integration then feel free to [join the project](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSCCNetPlugin) on CodePlex - I would love to have any help going.

Comment: I actually would like things that (I think) should already have space for in the ware house for TFS BUild Server, but I will be using CC.NET. I am thinking build name, result (Pass/Fail), Number of Warnings, Number of Errors, Time, UnitTests Run, UnitTests Passed, Code Coverage, FxCop results.

Comment: I will probably be working on this and letting you know what I have found over on codeplex. I have been using your plugin since I started CC.NET. But, What have you found so nice about TFSBuild? I have extended my CC.NET so far, I don't think TFS will ever work, but I'd like to hear.

Comment: Pushing build name, result, compilation and test summaries should be pretty do-able if you use the TFS API.  Unit test results possible with a bit of hackery (basically you XSLT the Nunit results into a .trx file). Code coverage etc very hard if not impossible in TFS2008.